# Result too large error for shmget()

Tags: c, windows, shared-memory, tuxedo

I wanted to access the shared memory of a Tuxedo application. So, I used shmget(key,0,0) in my code. It is returning error with error code 34, Result too large. My machine is a Windows server 2008 64 bit one.
I searched many forums but couldn't know the reason for this issue. Any help is much appreciated.
Below is the part of code:

```
if ( (shmid=shmget(shmkey, 0, 0)) == INVALID_IPC) 
{
LOG_SYS_ERR((TUX_FAILED_CONNECT_TO_SHM,shmkey));
return PCS_RC_ERROR;
}
```

I used visual studio 2010 to compile

Comment: Please provide your code for the `shmget` call and error handling, including declaration of the parameter variables. Also, which compiler are you using?

Comment: Why are you trying to allocate shared memory block of zero bytes? In Unix it's an error, the SHMMIN is 1 (and effectively - PAGE_SIZE).

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262029/how-to-attach-to-an-existing-shared-memory-segment

Comment: I am not creating the shared memory. Just trying to access already existing memory. Hence using 0 to get the shmid.

Comment: This is for a windows machine, not a unix machine.